# Conflicting overloads for Hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, overloading, hamcrest

The matcher [`IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.html) has two overloads for the static factory method `containsInAnyOrder` (both have the return type `Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>>`):

1. `containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection<Matcher<? super T>> itemMatchers)`
2. `containsInAnyOrder(Matcher<? super T>... itemMatchers)`

Now consider the following program:

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo","bar"), 
                       containsInAnyOrder(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar")));
    }

}
```

When executing this as a JUnit test, it passes, as expected. It uses the second overload of `containsInAnyOrder` shown above.

Now, when I change the assertion to this (which exactly matches the example given in the [documentation of the first overload](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.html#containsInAnyOrder%28java.util.Collection%29)):

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo","bar"), 
           containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it doesn't compile anymore, because now the compiler infers the return type of `containsInAnyOrder` to be

```
Matcher<Iterable<? extends List<Matcher<String>>>>
```

It seems like the compiler still chooses the second overload. If it used the first one, the example should work. Why does it behave like this? How can I make this work?

I am using Hamcrest 1.3 and Oracle Java 1.7.

Answer (score 4):

It actually matches both overloaded methods. I'm not sure why exactly the first one is chosen, but you can provide a hint to make it choose the correct method.

By casting the argument to `Collection`:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo","bar"),
        containsInAnyOrder((Collection)Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));
```

or by specifying the generic type T as `<String>` (don't work with static import, though):

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo","bar"),
        IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.<String>containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));
```

Comment: I recommend the second version for type safety. Additionally you can write `Matchers.<String>containsInAnyOrder` instead of `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.<String>containsInAnyOrder`.

Answer (score 4):

This is even a bit harder when you are matching your own objects, rather than simple strings, to get the generics to work out. If you are using the varargs `containsInAnyOrder(Matcher<? super T>... itemMatchers)` as in the question's first example you will get a *Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter* warning. For example:

```
assertThat(myDTOList, 
    containsInAnyOrder(sameStateAs(expectedMyDTO1), sameStateAs(expectedMyDTO2));
```

One way to then solve the problem the OP stated in the question, is to define your collection of matchers as follows:

```
Collection<Matcher<? super MyDTO>> expectedMyDTOs = 
    Arrays.<Matcher<? super MyDTO>>asList(sameStateAs(expectedMyDTO1), sameStateAs(expectedMyDTO2));

// Use like this:
assertThat(myDTOList, 
    containsInAnyOrder(expectedMyDTOs);
```

Comment: wow, `? super MyDTO` did the trick. `? super Object` did not : ) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

With hamcrest 1.3 you are able to use the `Matchers` class instead of `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder` directly as mentioned by @eee. Matchers actually just calls IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder for you.

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest
{
    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo","bar"), 
            Matchers.<OrderValidationStep>containsInAnyOrder("foo", "bar"));
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot use a static import if you want to `Type` your call to containsInAnyOrder, and this removes the need to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`